# using self joins in sub query

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, self-join

In certain cases, there is a null value for a variable so I am using a case statement to retrieve the data from another table-
However, it requires a self join that seems to fail.

to be more explicit, I am attempting to obtain a child's patient record number when another record number is not present -normally due to child being born outside the system. I have the mother's patient record number and the child's birthdate in another table (CESR)-

I am attempting to rejoin a members coverage table when the null value occurs as all the members fall under one coverage_id 
so that you can have

```
COVERAGE_ID PAT_MRN_ID      BIRTH_DATE
3123xxxx    110010xxxxx1    2/14/198x  12:00:00 AM
3123xxxx    110010xxxxx2    1/11/201x  12:00:00 AM
3123xxxx    110010xxxxx3    10/6/201x  12:00:00 AM
3123xxxx    110010xxxxx4    10/4/198x  12:00:00 AM
```

The cohort table would have

```
PAT_MRN_ID  Outcome
110010xxxxx1    1/11/201x  12:00:00 AM
```

but the record I want returned is #2 from above

```
select distinct CESR.PAT_MRN_ID,CESR.PREG_OUTCOME_DATE,
       HSP_LD_MOM_CHILD.pat_enc_csn_id,
       HSP_LD_MOM_CHILD.CHILD_ENC_CSN_ID,
       pat_enc_hsp.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,
       pat_enc_hsp.HOSP_DISCH_TIME,     
       case when HSP_LD_MOM_CHILD.CHILD_ENC_CSN_ID is null then 
--The problem statement below--
      (select COVERAGE_MEMBER_LIST2.MEM_NUMBER 
         from HCCLNC.COVERAGE_MEMBER_LIST 
         inner join cOVERAGE_MEMBER_LIST cOVERAGE_MEMBER_LIST2 
                 on cOVERAGE_MEMBER_LIST.coverage_id=cOVERAGE_MEMBER_LIST2.coverage_id
         inner join patient patient2 
                 on cOVERAGE_MEMBER_LIST2.pat_id=patient2.pat_id 
                and CESR.PREG_OUTCOME_DATE=trunc(patient2.birth_date)    
              where a.pat_id = COVERAGE_MEMBER_LIST.pat_id) else ' '  end as mem_number 
  --end--                                               
  from bx.CESR_COHORT CESR 
 inner join patient A 
    on CESR.pat_mrn_id=a.pat_mrn_id
  left join pat_enc_hsp on a.pat_id=pat_enc_hsp.pat_id         
   and CESR.PREG_OUTCOME_DATE between trunc(pat_enc_hsp.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME) 
   and trunc(pat_enc_hsp.HOSP_DISCH_TIME) 
  left join HSP_LD_MOM_CHILD 
    on pat_enc_hsp.pat_enc_csn_id=HSP_LD_MOM_CHILD.pat_enc_csn_id
 where a.pat_id in ('xxx');
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit-def much more readable!

Comment: plz share the ORA-error. Assuming, the query is returning multiple rows (ORA-01427) or may be error at trunc..date-numeric error ..

Comment: If I can repeat the error-sure. it is not a date error but rather a parallel (or multi-row) error.